# Section Boxes escaping Div Tag when using 100% Height of viewport for responsive website

Tags: html, css

I am currently build the front end to a website using 100% height, so each section of the site takes up the viewport of display. (The site should look similar to others that use this technique such as Square Cash.)

The desktop site looks fine, but when making the site responsive the height does not stretch to the content. Making blocks run over the section. This may be because the height is set to 100% so it stops there.

The first welcome section is fine, but the second part of the site consists of 4 boxes (section tags) resting inside of a div tag. I am trying to get the boxes to be responsive staying within the container.

HTML:

```
<div class="top-section">
<nav> 
 <div class="nav-logo"><img></div>
 <a href="#registerpage" class="button">Register</a>
</nav>      
   <div id="center-column">
     <h1>WELCOME</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="text-banner">      
     <h6></h6>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom-section">
<div id="center-box">
    <section>
      <h6></h6><p></p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h6></h6><p></p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h6></h6><p></p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h6></h6><p></p>
    </section>
 </div>
 </div>
```

CSS desktop:

```
   html, body{
   height:100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   }

   .top-section{
   height:100%;
   background-color: #3498DB;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   text-align: center;
   }

   #center-column {
   position: relative;
   margin: 0;
   margin-top: 10%;
   margin-bottom: 5em;
   padding: 0;
   }

   .bottom-section{
   height:100%;
   background-color: #9B59B6;
   margin: 0;}

   #center-box { 
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;}

    section { 
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #8E44AD;
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    }
```

CSS MOBILE:

```
    html, body{
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }


   .top-section{
   height:100%;
   background-color: #3498DB;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   text-align: center;
   }

   #center-column {
   position: relative;
   margin: 0;
   margin-top: 10%;
   margin-bottom: 5em;
   padding: 0;
   }

   .bottom-section{
    min-height:100%;
    background-color: #9B59B6;
    margin: 0;}

   #center-box { 
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;}


    section { 
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    background-color: #8E44AD;
    height: 12em;
    width: 90%;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using different percentages which total to 100% or less (including margins, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, using percentages for mobile and tablet views helped with the responsiveness of the site. 

I found the problem I was having was due to floating the section boxes to the left on mobile which caused them to escape the div tags. Setting float to none resolved this problem.